# Use a function a → b as "monadic" function a → m b

Tags: haskell, monads, function-composition, pointfree

I am currently playing around with Haskell basics and stumbled upon the following "use case":

```
ghci> let divideTenBy x | x == 0 = Nothing | otherwise = Just (10 / x)
ghci> let composed = divideTenBy <=< return . (*10) <=< divideTenBy <=< return . (-)5
ghci> Just 5 >>= composed
Nothing
ghci> Just 10 >>= composed
Just (-0.5)
```

So I'm basically mixing monadic and pure functions here and compose them into a monadic function. This works, but the `return . (*10)` seems to me like a commonly needed thing, so I'm tempted to define a shorthand for it, something like `monadify = (return.)`.

Before I do that, though, I'd like to ask if there are already helpers to deal with that kind of situation. Of course I could also be confused about the whole thing and there are reasons why this should not be done. If so, please tell me.

Comment: Also note that `mu >>= return . f === liftM f mu === fmap f mu` (the latter requires a `Functor` instance, but all decent `Monad`s have one). As Daniel Wagner's answer illustrates, `return . f >=> foo === foo . f`. In the other argument position of `(>=>)` it's not quite as nice, `foo >=> return . f === fmap f . foo`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no reason not to do it. However, it's rarely necessary. For example, your use case can be rewritten as

```
composed = divideTenBy . (*10) <=< divideTenBy . (-)5
```

Comment: I'm surprised this didn't occur to me, it's actually quite obvious :) I guess this answers the question perfectly well, thank you!